# Can I push code to GitHub from my local machine while editing on a remote machine?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I use [VSCode Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to make changes directly on my project server - this makes testing and debugging much quicker than constantly pushing and pulling from GitHub. However, when I do a git commit and push from VSCode, it appears in GitHub as though it was pushed from my server (using its corresponding SSH key) rather than from my local machine and personal account. This means that any changes I make appear to come from a generic "Server" author and are not attached to my name. I would prefer that any changes I make are reflected under my own name and not the generic server account. Is this possible?

Comment: use the `--author` option of `git commit`, use the command line to commit

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run these commands in the integrated terminal:

git config --global user.name "Your Name"

git config --global user.email youremail@example.com

Comment: now the next user using the server will commit as `John Doe`

Comment: Right, if there are multiple people using the server, I would recommend using the `--author` option as you commented.

Comment: why modify it for all repos on the server, why not use `--local`